# if javascript event = true then fire vbscript

Tags: javascript, vbscript

I am assigned to maintain a piece of code where validation was done in vb.script. 
This is the button's code which fires the vbscript:

```
<input id="btn"  type="button"nonclick="ValidateVB();" runat="server" />
```

I do not want to code in VBScript. I want to do the new work in javascript.
How can I first run the javascript function ValidateJS() and then if it returns true, run ValidateVB?

I tried

```
<input id="btn"  type="button" 
onclientclick="return ValidateJS()" onclick="ValidateVB();" runat="server" />

<input id="btn"  type="button" value="Validate" 
 onclick="ValidateJS();ValidateVB();" runat="server" />

<input id="btn"  type="button" value="Validate" 
 onclick="return ValidateJS();ValidateVB();" runat="server" />
```

but to no avail...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
onclick="(function(){if(ValidateJS()) ValidateVB();})()"
```

Comment: Or a bit more concise: `onclick="ValidateJS() && ValidateVB()"`. There's also no need for the wrapper function (see @nicael's answer), `onclick` attribute event handlers are implicitly wrapped in functions.

Comment: Thanks. I think you have to put onclick="ValidateJS() && ValidateVB()" as an answer. It seems to be the best way for me...

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use an `if` statement:

```
onclick="if(ValidateJS()){ValidateVB()}"
```